# elgg installation with xampp

Tags: php, xampp, elgg

I am trying to install elgg 2.3.0 in windows with Apache 2.4.53 and php 8.1.5 and set all instructions this link http://learn.elgg.org/en/stable/intro/install/xampp.html but when i run instalaition page with browser from localhost show me fatal error :

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\elgg\elgg\engine\lib\input.php on line 290

Fatal error: During inheritance of IteratorAggregate: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function _elgg_php_error_handler(), 4 passed in D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\ParameterBag.php on line 19 and exactly 5 expected in D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\elgg\elgg\engine\lib\elgglib.php:964 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\ParameterBag.php(19): _elgg_php_error_handler(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'D:\xampp\htdocs...', 298) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(414): include('D:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(301): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('D:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php(240): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\Compone...') #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php(222): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request->initialize(Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, NULL) #5 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php(1942): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request->__construct(Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, NULL) #6 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Request.php(281): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createRequestFromFactory(Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array) #7 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals(Object(Elgg\Di\ServiceProvider)) #8 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\elgg\elgg\engine\classes\Elgg\Di\DiContainer.php(68): call_user_func(Array, Object(Elgg\Di\ServiceProvider)) #9 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\elgg\elgg\engine\classes\Elgg\Di\DiContainer.php(48): Elgg\Di\DiContainer->build(Array, 'request') #10 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\elgg\elgg\engine\classes\Elgg\Http\Input.php(87): Elgg\Di\DiContainer->__get('request') #11 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\elgg\elgg\engine\classes\Elgg\I18n\Translator.php(160): Elgg\Http\Input->get('hl') #12 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\elgg\elgg\engine\classes\Elgg\I18n\Translator.php(145): Elgg\I18n\Translator->detectLanguage() #13 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\elgg\elgg\engine\classes\Elgg\I18n\Translator.php(325): Elgg\I18n\Translator->getCurrentLanguage() #14 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\elgg\elgg\engine\classes\ElggInstaller.php(95): Elgg\I18n\Translator->registerTranslations('D:/xampp/htdocs...', true) #15 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\elgg\elgg\engine\classes\Elgg\Application.php(483): ElggInstaller->__construct() #16 D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\install.php(11): Elgg\Application::install() #17 {main} in D:\xampp\htdocs\sites\elgg\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\ParameterBag.php on line 19

Answer (score 0):

Elgg 2.3.0 doesn't support PHP 8.
Switch on PHP 7.4 or use [the latest Elgg version](https://elgg.org/about/download)